# NET::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM error for google chrome stable version on ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

I am recently updated my google chrome to stable version and from then I am getting this error "NET::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM" while visiting some sites like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d
```

This will probably solve the issue

Comment: Thank you @rajeev :) I have been suffering for a week for this problem :)

Comment: Also need to upgrade libnss3.

Comment: Upgrade libnss3:

Add "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main" to /etc/apt/source.list. Then sudo apt-get update. sudo apt-get upgrade libnss3.

Comment: oh man i got it when use windows, what should i do?